# JQuery Post Not Passing Data Values to Php File

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am using the jQuery function $.post to pass some values to a php file, which then uses those values to refer to a mySQL database and parse out the resulting value in the post success function. However for some reason when I try and grab the data in the php file using the $_POST tag I am getting the notice that the indexes are undefined. Here is my js code:

```
var curX = 2;
var curY = 6;

function move(moveX, moveY) {
var position = {
    x: curX + moveX,
    y: curY + moveY
}
$.post('php/tilecheck.php', position, function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    curX += moveX;
    curY += moveY;

    var n = data.split("\"");
    boundary(n[3], n[1]);
    boundary(n[7], n[5]);
    boundary(n[11], n[9]);
    boundary(n[15], n[13]);
    /*boundary(data.left,'left');
    boundary(data.right, 'right');
    boundary(data.top, 'top');
    boundary(data.bottom, 'bottom');*/
})
}

function boundary(value, pos) {
if(value == 1){
    $("#a" + pos).css('display', 'none');
}
else {
    $("#a" + pos).css('display', '');
}
}
```

And the php file it refers to:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('db-info.php');

$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE xpos = ".($x - 1)." AND ypos = $y LIMIT 1";
    $lefttile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE xpos = ".($x + 1)." AND ypos = $y LIMIT 1";
    $righttile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE xpos = $x AND ypos = ".($y - 1)." LIMIT 1";
    $toptile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $q = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE xpos = $x AND ypos = ".($y + 1)." LIMIT 1";
    $bottomtile = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));

    $json = array(
        "left" => $lefttile['bound'], "right" => $righttile['bound'],
        "top" => $toptile['bound'], "bottom" => $bottomtile['bound']
    );

    $output = json_encode($json);
    echo $output;
}
else
    echo "No value";
?>
```

Whats weird is even though the values are undefined in the php, it still outputs the correct data in an array, which is confirmed by the console log. However, to access those values in the array I have to use the fixed call to the function boundary(), while the commented out code doesn't work. Please let me know if you have any ideas or questions. Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you use this - console.log(data);
And are you sure that this url > 'php/tilecheck.php' is correct ? 
Make one test ECHO on the first line of your PHP code to know that its working..

Comment: Like I said, the console log outputs the correct array ({"left":"1","right":"1","top":"0","bottom":"1"}), but I am unable to reference it outside the fix I applied. I already have checked the php using echo and it is indeed working.

Comment: Check your network tab in developer tools.. or firebug.. to see if you are sending the params over correctly

Comment: I don't get it. Is the error in PHP or JavaScript? BTW, in $.post() you have to add 'json' as the last argument to tell jQuery that you are expecting JSON. ;)

Comment: @wirey Whenever I call the function that passes the values through $.post, the network tab shows this: NAME: tilecheck.php, METHOD: POST, STATUS: 200/OK, TYPE: text/html. It seems to be passing it correctly.

Comment: Post will show up as ok.. but you need to check the params passed.. inside Network>Headers.. it will show your params/values passed to your php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One try from me .. You have JSON responde.. so you can use it.

!! There is need to be added one check before the LOOP, to see if the responde is successfull or not how ever this is my idea ..

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/tilecheck.php', 
    data: position, 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key,value){
                if(value == 1){
                    $("#a" + key).css('display', 'none');
                }
                else {
                    $("#a" + key).css('display', '');
                }
            });
    }   
    });
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work :(. The outcome was similar to when I tried my original code, so I think there might be a problem with how the php file receives or passes the values. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: try it with .ajax instead .post

Comment: oh wow, this works! thank you! not that i care too much, just curious, but the php is still throwing the notice of an undefined $_POST index. would you know why? and would you know why .ajax worked, and .post didn't, if you don't mind?

Answer (score -2):

Check what you get from jQuery in PHP :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and check the proper naming of 'x' and 'y'

Comment: `printf();` does not support arrays, and `$_printf();` is rather invalid. You might mean `print_r();`, which is best used within a `<pre>` element

Comment: It was a typo, sorry. I meant print_r() to check the post values. And you can see what is actually posted from jquery.